# The page isn't redirecting correctly?

Tags: rsa

I have a CentOS 6 VPS with GoDaddy:

- OS: Linux CentOS
- RAM: 4 GB
- Storage: 120 GB‡‡
- Bandwidth: 4,000 GB/mo

I have set up my domain/nameservers etc fine.

As I’m using Plesk 11 I had to install mcrypt via SSH which I did successfully (via following IgorG’s tut: http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?281420-Adding-mcrypt-extension-to-php-on-plesk-11). I then installed the Magento app to:
Installation path:
http://FifaUltimateTeamCoins.co.uk

It installed fine and I can log into the admin panel.

However, when I try to load my website I receive the error:

```
The page isn’t redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
```

I spoke to a chat operator for servers on GoDaddy and he believes that there is an error in the content or my server doesn’t meet the requirements of Magento?

So I checked my error logs and they come back as:

```
[Sat Jul 20 14:03:52 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel’ does NOT match server name!?

[Sun Jul 21 00:20:13 2013] [error] [client 146.255.32.95] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind:)

[Sun Jul 21 03:07:52 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel’ does NOT match server name!?

[Sun Jul 21 07:48:23 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel’ does NOT match server name!?

[Sun Jul 21 07:55:41 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel’ does NOT match server name!?

[Sun Jul 21 14:01:36 2013] [error] [client 212.7.196.88] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): (Can't post more links):)

[Mon Jul 22 01:03:37 2013] [error] [client 5.200.39.77] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): (Can't post more links):)

[Mon Jul 22 02:34:37 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel’ does NOT match server name!?

[Mon Jul 22 02:34:37 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel’ does NOT match server name!?

[Mon Jul 22 02:50:19 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel’ does NOT match server name!?
```

Does anybody know what the above error means - is that stopping the website from loading?
Or does my server not meet all of Magento’s requirements?
Or is it because I haven’t uploaded a theme to my website yet?

(I’m new to Magento)

Many thanks!
Jamie

Comment: The certificate should not be causing a redirect loop. More likely a configuration error. Try removing elements from the process to hopefully identify more precisely in which area the problem lies. I assume you are using Apache. Could be in the web server config (or htaccess file).

Comment: These errors are standard in Plesk systems, but they haven't got anything to do with your problem. Note that Plesk has separate apache logs for every domain. You find them at /var/www/vhosts/<domainname>/statistics/logs/. Check the error log there for messages.

Comment: Solved it!
It was because the Plesk install that Parallel provide it codes a bad redirect that causes it to go to that page with the error that will never resolve. So I did a manual install of Magento and it now works fine!

Thanks for the help guys, it's appreciated :)